# Is there any soltion to "validation.ts:145 Uncaught Error "?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error

````
validation.ts:145 Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'messages.-MS6_zD3OURA8VJbSsOd.email'     
at iu (validation.ts:145)     
at validation.ts:204     
at Sa (util.ts:417)     
at iu (validation.ts:185)     
at Ga (validation.ts:122)     
at Ol.set (Refere
```
````

--Java Script Starts Here--

```
     // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCrbgYvaGmfje2In9nOOW6pyTpKV967MAs",
    authDomain: "goldybai-s-website.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "goldybai-s-website",
    storageBucket: "goldybai-s-website.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "584274595197",
    appId: "1:584274595197:web:b7621d56037143b18f9014"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Reference messages collection
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");

// Listen for form submit

document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
// Submit form
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get values
  var name = getInputVal("name").value;
  var email = getInputVal("email").value;
  var phone = getInputVal("phone").value;
  var message = getInputVal("message").value;

    // Save message
    saveMessage((name, email, phone, message));
//   console.log(name);
}


// Function to get get form values

function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(name, email, phone, message) {
    var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
    newMessageRef.set({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        message: message,
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Christchurch - Hair - Cuts</title>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container">
        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">

            <ul class="main-menu ">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="right-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <!-- Log In Form -->

    <div class="form-container">
        <h1 class="brand">Bookings</h1>
        <div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">
            <div class="company-info">
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-road"></i>Cobra St Christchurch</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>(022) 173-6590</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>sukh@gmail.com</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="contact">
                <h3>Let Us Know!</h3>

<!-- @TODO - Validation -->
                <form id="contactForm" autocomplete="on">
                    <p>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name= "name" id="name">
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name= "email" id="email">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name= "phone" id="phone">
                    </p>
                    <!-- <p>
                        <input type="datetime-local" id="haircut" name="Haircut">
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <input list="haircut" name="haircut">
                        <datalist id="haircut-types">
                        <option value="Baby">
                        <option value="Men">
                        <option value="Women">
                        </datalist>
                    </p> -->
                      
                    <p class="full">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p class="full">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

         <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy &cookies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trademarks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&copy; Christchurch Cuts 2021</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Contac Form */

.form-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.brand {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;  
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(51, 51, 51);
}

.wrapper > *{
    padding: 1rem;
}

.company-info {
    background: #333;
}

.company-info h3, 
.company-info ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;

}

.contact h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* Form Styles */
.contact form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.contact form label {
    display: block;
}

.contact form p {
    margin: 0;
}

.contact form .full {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.contact form button, 
.contact form input, 
.contact form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding:  1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.contact form button {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact form button:hover, .contact form button:focus {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite explicit:

> Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'messages.-MS6_zD3OURA8VJbSsOd.email'

You're passing a value of `undefined` to the database, which is not allowed. The path where you're passing `undefined` is `messages.-MS6_zD3OURA8VJbSsOd.email`, so that means that the value if `email` is `undefined` in this code:

```
newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    message: message,
})
```

I recommend running the code in a debugger, and looking at `email` on this line.

If email can be `undefined` and your code should handle that, the simplest fix is probably something like this:

```
newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    email: email || "",
    phone: phone,
    message: message,
})
```

Comment: thanks for this is there any way to store Date value to firebase database what I was trying to is I have booking page for hair cut appointments every time a new booking has to be made then they have to select a particular date and time for the appointment but that's something not working for me please can you help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies where you are getting the `input` fields values:

```
var name = getInputVal("name").value;
var email = getInputVal("email").value;
var phone = getInputVal("phone").value;
var message = getInputVal("message").value;
```

In the `getInputVal` function, you are already returning the `value`.

Instead, try this:

```
var name = getInputVal("name");
var email = getInputVal("email");
var phone = getInputVal("phone");
var message = getInputVal("message");
```

Comment: thanks for this is there any way to store Date value to firebase database what I was trying to is I have booking page for hair cut appointments every time a new booking has to be made then they have to select a particular date and time for the appointment but that's something not working for me please can you help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: I am afraid that is a different topic you are asking about now. You should post a separate question for this one. And in the mean time, if you have been able to solve your problem, then please accept the answer as your solution whichever helped you out.